# Kerberos authentication for Twisted Python client/server

Tags: python, windows, active-directory, twisted, kerberos

**Task:** add Kerberos active directory authentication to an insecure reporting and data manipulation desktop application. This app is...

- written in Stackless Python 2.7
- uses Twisted for client-server interactions
- Client is compiled to an exe and runs on Windows
- Servers run on Linux (Red Hat)

**Currently** we pull the Windows network ID (logon name) from the user's account and pass to the server, which looks up what permissions that user is configured to have, and passes back menu options which provide access just to those features. Main weakness is that one could send a different username to the server and access other permissions.

Therefore Kerberos. (And LDAP, from what I read.)

**Question:**

Does Twisted provide a built-in Kerberos setup?
[authkerb](https://libraries.io/pypi/authkerb) perhaps?

I found authkerb after a ton of searching, but I don't see feedback from anyone using it. I'm not sure where to start. If anyone has experience with this, or if you've run across any relevant info to **implementing Kerberos specifically with Twisted**, I'd appreciate it immensely!

---

I've never touched anything like Kerberos before, so I read up on it:

```
kerberos.org/software/tutorial.html  
technet.microsoft.com/library/cc961976  
web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-latest/doc/appdev/init_creds.html  
web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.12/doc/user/tkt_mgmt.html
```

Also found tips on what to avoid:

```
faqs.org/faqs/kerberos-faq/general/section-83.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twisted does not.

However, http://calendarserver.org, which is bassed on Twisted, does have kerberos authentication, and was the originator of the https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pykerberos project.  It should serve as a workable example.

Comment: Thank you! That's helpful. I can't upvote yet, but I upvoted in spirit.

Comment: You're quite welcome. Good luck! Despite having worked on CalendarServer myself for quite some time, I don't actually have a grasp of the kerberos parts, so I'm happy to help connect people with the tech so we get more people in the community who know how to put these tools together :)